# Do I need to explain my reasoning when choosing between two offers

Tags: faculty-application, interview, interpersonal-issues

I have been lucky enough to have been offered different professor positions in different universities. Both departments have made a lot of efforts to try and convince me to choose theirs (who gets offered what job is public here).

It was not easy, but I have finally chosen one. Should I try to explain why to the people from the other department, the one I am not going to? This is not obvious, because while there are arguments I could make, my decision relies in large part on extra-academic concerns, and some gut feeling. However, such an explanation may be expected, and I do not want to burn any bridges.

Comment: Where is this (e.g. what country)? In my experience no explanation is needed, but my culture may be different from yours; for instance, job offers are not public here.

Comment: @NateEldredge I would rather not say. My situation is specific enough that it could be enough to personally identify me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No.  You do not need to explain your decision.**

Assuming it's actually true, it would be *appropriate* to tell the department you're turning down that their offer was attractive, and that it was a difficult decision, and that the choice came down to non-academic factors that were out of their control.  But even this is more than you *need* to tell them.

Comment: I think even disclosing this much could be risky. Depends what was discussed at the interview. At least in the US committees probe as much as they can about outside factors (and of course you tell them what they want to hear) because they hate to make an offer that won't get accepted and miss out on their next choice. They might feel the candidate promised them that according to all extra-academic concerns they would be a favorite choice.

Comment: _They might feel the candidate promised them..._ — Being rejected is never easy.  There is no way to prevent the person/institution you are rejecting from being hurt, or feeling used, or using the rejection as an excuse to burn bridges. I'm suggesting an honest response that allows the search committee an opportunity to save face. It's their own fault If they don't take it.

Answer (score 3):

**You don't *need* to tell them, but it is a nice thing to do:** Since your decision came down to non-academic considerations, it would be a nice gesture to thank them for the offer and explain that you preferred the other university for reasons that are not within their control.  Just as job applicants like to get useful feedback on an unsuccessful application, and a guy who gets turned down for a date wants to know why (is it something wrong with me?!), employers generally benefit from knowing why they were unable to recruit the candidate they wanted.  I would leave out the bit about the 'gut feeling', but it is worth mentioning the other factors that led to your decision.